# Making video load faster in videoview

Tags: android, performance, video-processing, android-videoview

I play a video in a videoview from an URL...everything works fine and even the video plays

But the only problem is that the video takes almost 10 seconds to start playing which might be kind of annoying to the user

I have tried different URLs and its the same, the videos are 360p and 6sec long

Is it the default media player that is slow?

I have the stack overflow but could not find a suitable answer and ever searched for various 3 rd party videos libraries but could not find one

Even tried google's exoplayer library but the documentation is not that good in my view

Is there any solution how to overcome this problem?

**my code**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            String videeourl = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp";

            VideoView videoView = (FastVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
            videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            videoView.setVideoPath(videeourl); 

            videoView.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post some code for us to see what you are doing

Comment: @NizaSiwale posted the code PS

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with your internet connection? Maybe it's slow. Try to load a video from the phone and see how fast it loads

Comment: @NizaSiwale nope even tested it my intenet is fast enogh at 6.7mbps

Comment: Try to parse your URL like this 
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(videourl); then use videoView.setVideoURI(uri).

Comment: @NizaSiwale even tried that method also by searching online but still the same

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this? i am facing the same problem..

Comment: Have got any solution for the problem. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Exoplayer. You can find the open source project here:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

It uses Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH),breaks long content into HTTP segments.

Comment: Ya saw it but how to use it is not given in a easy manner.its very complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this tutorial step-by-step to integrate **ExoPlayer** (*ExoPlayer is the video player running in the Android YouTube app.*) to your app, it's not that complicated as you thought. 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/index.html#0

By the way, there are a lot of good assignments in **Google CodeLabs**, you should check it out.